# Custom wordpress post filter

Tags: php, wordpress, filter

So I have a page of posts and I would like to be able to filter the posts by month, category, and a keyword filter that a user enters. I have found some examples online of plugins that will accomplish the keyword and category and keyword fields, but I am not seeing an easy way to add the month selector. Would it be easier to make a custom filter form myself? The only issue I am seeing with that is the keyword filter.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best solution is using AJAX. You can create inputs in template where all posts show then define logic and javasctipt files in functions.php and finally add js files.